# is there a single command to determine if a variable is part of a defined set

Tags: c#

Kind hard to word the question, but for example, say I want something like:

```
int x = 5;
int z[] = {1,12,22,56};

if ((x==z[0]) || (x==z[1]) || (x==z[2]) || (x==z[3])) {
     [self fooOnYou:x]
}
```

Is there a cleaner or more elegant way to do this?

Comment: You tag it C, C# (which have two different answers) and you used objective C code. which one are you asking about?

Comment: Yes - have a look at the Array methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e23tz9hz.aspx

Comment: The array is 4 elements long, but you check for the fifth element `[4]`. Are you intending that and intending to skip element `[1]` as well?

Comment: Agree, the answer depends entirely on the language you are targeting.  C#, for example, has many set operations that would make this fairly trivial...

Answer (score 1):

The C# answer could be:

```
using System.linq;
...
if (z.Any(i => i == x))
{
    // Do your stuff here.
}
```

Comment: It is meant to be an exact copy from the example in the question.

Comment: `Contains()` would be simpler than `Any()` for this purpose, but `Any()` works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Contains()` in the `System.Linq` namespace:

```
int x = 5;
int[] z = new {1,12,22,56};

if (z.Contains(x)) 
{
     // do your stuff here...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are trying to find out whether an integer value is present in an array of integer values. If the array is sorted you should use the [Binary Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) algorithm to find that value. If it is not (and you do not want to sort it), you could use a simple for loop to find the desired value:

```
int findValue(int value, int array[], int size) {

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if (array[i] == value) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I'm not so sure. The question is asking for a `subset` and is skipping element(s).

Comment: Correct -- I suppose you could pass additional arguments to create a desired subset of indices to test. In any case, he should use Linq or something more efficient (and already proven to work).

Answer (score -1):

Loop throug the array. Something like 
For(int i=0, i